# Custom dialog class does't show the dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

In order to make my app as much low maintenance as possible I've created a class Cl_dialog, that is supposed to manage the creation of each Dialog of my app:

```
public class Cl_Dialog
{
    private Activity activity;
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private View layout;

    public Cl_Dialog( Activity act )
    {
        this.activity    =   act;    
        builder         =   new AlertDialog.Builder( act );
        alertDialog     =   builder.create();
    }

    public void dialogShowDatePicker()
    {    
        setContentView( R.layout.dialog_datepicker);

        ( (ImageButton) layout.findViewById( R.id.btn_confirm ) ).setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view )
        {
            close();
        }
        });
    }

    private void setContentView( int idLayout)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService( activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        layout = inflater.inflate( idLayout, (ViewGroup ) activity.findViewById( R.id.mainLayout ) );

        builder.setView( layout );
        builder.create();
    }   
    public void show()
    {
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void close()
    {
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

The class is called sometimes by `Fragment` sometimes by `Activity`.

This is an example of `layout.xml` I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_navigation_check"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_confirm"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here an example of how I call it:

```
cl_dialog = new Cl_Dialog(activity.this);
cl_dialog.dialogShowDatePicker();
cl_dialog.show();
```

Any clue about where I am wrong in the code?

Anyway I am an old programmer and I am trying to arrange old code I wrote year ago, is still this the suggested way to create a custom dialog in android?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `setContentView` you call `builder.create()` without setting the result for the `alertDialog`